# How to skip documents in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, deno

i'm quite new to deno and mongodb. I'm trying to skip document for pagination.

Here's the code:

```
let { page } = Object.fromEntries(request.url.searchParams);
page = parseInt(page);
console.log(page);
console.log(typeof page);
let res = await users.find().skip((page - 1) * 10).limit(10);
console.log(res);
```

Here's the error i get:

```
2
number
TypeError: users.find(...).skip is not a function
    at userLoad (file:///C:/Users/shoti/OneDrive/Desktop/drreglog/router.js:42:34)
    at dispatch (https://deno.land/x/oak/middleware.ts:35:32)
    at https://deno.land/x/oak/router.ts:416:18
    at dispatch (https://deno.land/x/oak/middleware.ts:35:32)
    at composedMiddleware (https://deno.land/x/oak/middleware.ts:41:12)
    at dispatch (https://deno.land/x/oak/router.ts:420:28)
    at dispatch (https://deno.land/x/oak/middleware.ts:35:32)
    at Object.composedMiddleware [as middleware] (https://deno.land/x/oak/middleware.ts:41:12)
    at Application.#handleRequest (https://deno.land/x/oak/application.ts:190:21)
```

Comment: What MongoDB package are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using [`mongo`](https://deno.land/x/mongo) module

From the [source code](https://deno.land/x/mongo/ts/collection.ts#L14), `skip` and `limit` should be passed as `options` argument

```
let res = await users.find({}, { skip: (page - 1) * 10, limit: 10 })
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please change the code as follows and see whether it fixes the issue?

```
let res = await users.find({}).skip((page - 1) * 10).limit(10);
```